# What does sbrk(0) point to when initializing static variables?

Tags: c++, unix, memory

In the [sbrk(2) manual](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sbrk),

it states that

> Calling `sbrk()` with an increment of 0 can be used to find the
> current location of the program break.

How does this work when `sbrk(0)` is used to initialize a `static` variable?

Say,

```c
static void* current_heap = sbrk(0);
```

This curiosity stems from the typical compilation steps of C/C++ code determine the size of the data segment at compile time.

As shown in the diagram below,

[image: Memory layout]

[<sup>*Distributed under CC BY-SA 3.0*</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Program_memory_layout.pdf)

the initialized static variables are stored in the data segment. And as far as I know, the heap normally starts from the end of BSS and data segments.

How does `sbrk(0)` know where heap starts during compilation while other static variables might not have been determined?

UPDATE:

As noted by @EugeneSh, here's a working example compiled with `clang++`:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

static void* current_heap = sbrk(0);

int main() {
  std::cout << current_heap << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Did you check it actually compiles?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I successfully compiled the code containing a variable under namespace initialized with `sbrk(0)`.

Comment: Please post [mcve] then. I doubt it can compile (in C at least)

Comment: Another reason you should not ask about C/C++, but rather choose a specific language. As you can see these are totally different beasts.

Comment: @EugeneSh.Right. I removed the `c` tag from the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, this code is not valid:

```
static void* current_heap = sbrk(0);
```

Because an initializer for an object with static storage duration must be a compile time constant, which this is not.  So this code will fail to compile in C.

For C++, the function will be called when the program runs at some point before `main` is called.

So there is no compile-time call to `sbrk`.

As for what section this variable would reside in, it would most likely be in .bss because it is not initialized at compile time.  Indeed, if I compile your code with g++ the variable is placed in .bss.

Comment: Okay, I got it. So, at the point of the initialization, all the `static` variables are determined. Hence,  the behavior of `sbrk(0)` is expected? (in C++)

Comment: @PHD static variables with a constant initializer go in .data while uninitialized or non-constant initialized static variables go in .bss, and `sbrk` runs when the program is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Per the C standard, 6.7.9:

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

This is therefore not a valid initialization in C.

In C++ it would be a run-time initialization.